# window.getSelection().baseOffset is wrong

Tags: javascript, html, getselection

If you select any text below beginning at the first character `H`, it will say the `baseOffset` of the selection is `5`.  In my real-life case it says `7`.  How do I correct this?

```js
setInterval(()=>{
  console.log(window.getSelection().baseOffset);
}, 250);
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <body>
    <div id='main'data-alignment="center">
    Hello World!
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: How many space characters do you count between the end of `<div id='main'data-alignment="center">` and the first `H`? => The result is correct. (and this property is not in the specs (yet), better use `anchorOffset`)

Comment: Interesting.  Thanks, can you post this as an answer so I can give you Best Answer?  In my real-life case the problem was the same.  My formatter was indenting the text and I just didn't consider that's what it was.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The result is correct, you have exactly 5 space characters between the end of `<div id='main'data-alignment="center">` and the `H`, these will be counted as offset.

To avoid that, you can wrap your TextNode in a `<span>` element so that there is no offset.

Also, `baseOffset` is *[still](https://github.com/w3c/selection-api/issues/34)* not in the official specs, better use [`anchorOffset`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Selection/anchorOffset) which I think does approximately the same thing (but is supported in all browsers).

```js
document.onselectionchange = ()=>{
  console.log(window.getSelection().anchorOffset);
};
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <body>
    <div id='main'data-alignment="center">
      <span>Hello World!</span>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```